# Why do vba worksheet modules export as .cls modules?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to clean up my Excel VBA project by exporting all code modules and then re-importing them. I understand that there is no VBA Project export or import, and that this must be done one module at a time. I only have 10-15 modules in the project, so I am not willing to pay for software if I can do it myself.

When I a export a module in the Modules folder, it is written out as a .bas file, and I have no problem importing it. However, when I export a module in the Microsoft Excel Objects folder (e.g., Sheet1), it is written out as a .cls module. When I import it, it goes into the Class folder, rather than the Microsoft Excel Objects folder. I'm wondering whether this is an Excel bug, or if there is something I can do to fix it.

The screenshot below shows the VBE project explorer before and after "cleanup." In the After screenshot, Sheet2 does not have any code. I had to create Sheet2 because a Workbook needs at least one worksheet.
[image]

Comment: Please share the code you used.

Comment: So do you want to use code in order to import the .cls worksheet modules?

Comment: I'm doing this manually, not with code. If I'm posting in the wrong department, where should I post?

Comment: Ok, do you want to import the modules with code? that is possible if you would like to use vba to import your .bas and .cls files, which would probably be more efficient and enjoyable rather than manually importing the modules. Regardless, the tags you used are appropriate for the question.

Comment: `I had to create Sheet2 because a Workbook needs at least one worksheet` - it would appear you expected that exporting a sheet also exports its cells contents. It does not, it only exports the VBA code.

Comment: I understand that exporting a worksheet module like Sheet1 only exports the code and not the worksheet contents.  The problem is that exporting Sheet1 in my example writes a .cls file.

Comment: I don't see how this is a "problem"?  class modules are used to create custom objects, such as the "Worksheet" object. Seems like you may need to look into such basic definitions before asking an ill-concieved question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Error-Codes/program-with-class-modules

Comment: Class modules and Worksheet modules are not the same thing. I put most of my code in Worksheet modules. Many of my worksheet modules have Worksheet_Activate methods. If I export my Worksheet modules and then import them as Class modules, are you claiming that my Worksheet_Activate functions will run when I activate those worksheets?

Comment: No I am not claiming that nor did I say that... I did not say they are the same thing either. However, a worksheet is an object that contains properties and methods that can be accessed via VBA, and a class module can be used to create a custom object within your workbook. I was simply stating the logic behind why worksheet event modules export as a .cls file. because the worksheets are an object themselves.

Comment: and if you used code to import them, then we wouldn't be having this back and forth. You can use code to import your modules into the respective worksheet, and do this on a loop as well since you have multiple worksheet modules.

Comment: Thanks, Kurt. I came here to get an education, and you have definitely set me on the right path. I have never used Class modules in my VBA code.

Comment: No problem, I'd be happy to provide code that adds the worksheet modules into the worksheets if you can provide certain details such as the worksheet names, etc. If your clean up includes re-creating the worksheets, and you want specific sheet names to have specific modules imported into them, please provide these details and I would be happy to help.

Comment: Kurt, Thanks, but it would be overkill for my application, which consits of just four workooks. Each workbook has a few worksheet/workbook modules, forms and classes. I open an .xlsm, save it as an .xlsx, then open both and copy the modules from the .xlsm to the .xlsx, and thensave the .xlsx as a new "cleaned".xlsm.  For some of the workbooks, this resulted in a dramatic reduction in size, which suggests that some cobwebs have been removed. I tested the cleaned .xlsms and they work just fine. So for now, the manual method is good enough. Thanks for your help.